# visual studio 2017 publish error

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, web-deployment

Using WebDeploy to publish to an Azure Web Site fails with error:

Error       The target "GetCopyToPublishDirectoryItems" does not exist in the project.

Visual Studio 2017 RC - latest download

I created an empty ASP .net Core web project with 4.61 .net version
I created an empty Library with 4.61 .net version
I added the library as a dependency of the web project
I rebuilt the project
I published with web deploy - and got the error

I am using Windows 10

The same happened on a friend computer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

PM

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known issue with a fix forthcoming.  The following Github issue page has several workarounds:

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/543